# post to textfield using tcpdf

Tags: php, post, tcpdf

I am unsure if I am going about this correctly. Why using TCPDF when I attempt to post it returns an empty textfield?

```
$pdf->Cell(35, 5, 'Job Number ');
$pdf->TextField($_POST["jobnum"], 50, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the fourth `$opt` parameter see the [TCPDF TextField reference](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a71d382a4356e7fb3f9fa72e53642c09c) and [Acrobat API Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)

```
$pdf->TextField("jobnum", 50, 5, array(), array('v'=>$_POST["jobnum"] ) );
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot the enclosing brace at the end. How about now?

Comment: figured it out you were missing another ) at the end but this did work! thank you exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF requires the `TextField()` function to be like so: `TextField("string", number, number)`

so you need to make it like this:

```
$pdf->TextField("'".$_POST["jobnum"]."'", 50, 5);
```

Comment: i tried and it didnt work "$_POST["jobnum"]" gives an error so i tried '$_POST["jobnum"]' and "$_POST['jobnum']" and neither posted the results.

Comment: does the `POST` actually have data? try an `echo` to check that.

Comment: yes. I have it working with writehtmlcell but I want the user to be able to edit it.